# Command-line scp doesn't use case-insensitive autocomplete

Tags: linux, bash, scp

Auto-completing filenames (by pressing `TAB` after first characters of the filenames have been written) is case-sensitive both on my Ubuntu 13.04 box and on my Debian Squeeze box, when I use `scp`.

I have the following line in my `.inputrc`:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

and the case-insensitive autocompletion works fine on other shell programs.

## Examples

`<TAB>` here means pressing the `TAB` key.

### Correct behaviour

Currently, case-insensitive autocompletion works correctly on other shell programs, such as `cp` here:

```
$ cp my<TAB>
```

which yields, as expected:

```
$ cp MyFile
```

### Incorrect behaviour

When using `scp`, the case-insensitive autocompletion doesn't work. On this line, nothing happens:

```
$ scp my<TAB>
```

And I have to revert to using the tedious case-sensitive autocompletion, like here:

```
$ scp My<TAB>
```

which yields, as expected:

```
$ scp MyFile
```

## Possible workaround

Since this is a "recent" issue (i.e. this has been happening only for a few years or so), my guess is that this has something to do with the way some programs have autocompletable switches and other arguments, starting from some version of `bash`, but I'm unable to find out how to fix this specific problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  You mention SCP and tab completion, but in general, tab completion is handled locally.  Can you clarify where you're expecting tab completion to be case-insensitive, and where it currently is and is not case sensitive?

Comment: @ernie: I added some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian (and Ubuntu) install provide you with a mountain of shell completion functions (in the `bash-completion` package); the functions are stored in the directory `/etc/bash_completion.d` and the one you're interested in is `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh`.

As far as I can see, the way that script gets the list of possible completions is to issue the command `ls -aFld ${path}*`, where `${path}` is the word which needs completing, either on the remote machine -- using ssh -- or directly on the local machine.

In order for this to work in a case-insensitive manner, you need to arrange for the glob in that `ls` command executing on the remote system to be expanded case-insensitively, which means you want to `shopt -s nocaseglob` before the `ls` command is executed.

I think your ubuntu/debian are more recent than mine, but it's possible that the following patch will work on your system. Otherwise, you can probably figure out the necessary edit:

```
--- ssh.old     2013-09-17 16:07:38.000000000 -0500
+++ ssh         2013-09-17 16:06:25.000000000 -0500
@@ -275,3 +275,3 @@
         files=$( ssh -o 'Batchmode yes' $userhost \
-            command ls -aF1d "$path*" 2>/dev/null | \
+            builtin shopt -s nocaseglob ';' command ls -aF1d "$path*" 2>/dev/null | \
             sed -e 's/'$_scp_path_esc'/\\\\\\&/g' -e '/[^\/]$/d' )
@@ -281,3 +281,3 @@
         files=$( ssh -o 'Batchmode yes' $userhost \
-            command ls -aF1d "$path*" 2>/dev/null | \
+            builtin shopt -s nocaseglob ';' command ls -aF1d "$path*" 2>/dev/null | \
             sed -e 's/'$_scp_path_esc'/\\\\\\&/g' -e 's/[*@|=]$//g' \
@@ -303,6 +303,6 @@
     if $dirsonly ; then
-        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( command ls -aF1d $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
+        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( shopt -s nocaseglob; command ls -aF1d $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
             sed -e "s/$_scp_path_esc/\\\\&/g" -e '/[^\/]$/d' -e "s/^/$1/") )
     else
-        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( command ls -aF1d $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
+        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( shopt -s nocaseglob; command ls -aF1d $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
             sed -e "s/$_scp_path_esc/\\\\&/g" -e 's/[*@|=]$//g' \
```

Comment: scp does not do completion for items on the remote machine . . .

Comment: @ernie: scp doesn't, no. A bash script does (if you have it installed).

Comment: I had started writing an answer along the same lines but then found that I had no `/etc/bash_completion/ssh` (or anything else that could be relevant, like `scp`) on my Debian (LMDE) and yet can reproduce the OP's symptoms. If you have a `/etc/bash_completion/ssh`, which distribution are you using? I _think_ this is something different and `scp` does a different type of completion since it also bring out names from the `/etc/hosts` file. +1 anyway for a good answer!

Comment: @terdon: it's /etc/bash_completion.d/ssh and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. It's a debian package called `bash-completion`. I don't know what other mechanism your distro would have, but the completions functions are visible if you type `set`, so you can probably find where they're being loaded from. I found a function called `_known_hosts_real` in `/etc/bash_completion` which looks through various ssh config files for known hosts, but bash knows how to look through /etc/hosts already: try `compgen -A hostname`

Comment: The file I had to edit on Ubuntu 13.04 was `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/scp`, after which your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @rici Sorry, I meant `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh`. I don't have it and yet still see the same behavior as the OP. I did not know about `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` though and there I did have an `scp` script. Cool :)

Comment: @terdon: One of the things that frustrates me about ubuntu is that it has the philosophy that its users are completely uninterested in its innards. In an ideal world, perhaps, but since the software is not perfect and the project(s) depend on us to help fix problems, the packagers should IMHO at least make it easier to figure out what's going on. Including actual README and CHANGES files and links to project pages would help. </rant>. Anyway, http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob;f=CHANGES;h=a4e8bcf80feaccd97e9bd0910b4dc0a7a06c152a;hb=HEAD#l324

Comment: @rici well Ubuntu is designed for newbies who don't want the innards. That's why I don't use it :)

Comment: @terdon: fair enough but is debian any better? The packaging is the same. How would you have found the configuration path change I noted in my comment? (disclaimer: I'm a FreeBSD refugee.)

Comment: Well, it's in the [README](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob_plain;f=README) and the packaging is not the same, Ubuntu is not compatible with Debian repos. It is only the package _manager_ that is the same.